# SAS Proc SQL function in where clause for only current week

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql

I have some data in week-date-time format ie 14dec2020 00:00:00:0000. I am using SAS and a proc sql query

This data contains many weeks worth of data but i was curious if theres in way to only pull data relevant to only current week? IE today is 17dec2020 so i would want to only pull data for the week of 14dec2020. if today was 22dec2020 then i would want it to pull data for the week of 21dec2020.

Here is one of the many queries i have tried.

```
data have;
  today = today();    
  wkday = weekday(today); 

  start = today - (wkday - 1);  
  end = today + (7 - wkday); 

  length cstart cend $30;
  cstart = put(start, date9.) || ' 00:00:00.0000' ;
  cend = put(end, date9.) || ' 00:00:00.0000' ;

  call symput('start', cstart);
  call symput('end', cend);
run; 


Proc Sql;
  connect to odbc (environment=x user=y p=z);
  create table basic.curweek as select * from connection to odbc
       (select year, month, week, store, sales, SKU
            from datatable
            where (&start. <= week <= &end.)
            order by sku);
 disconnect from odbc;
 quit;
```

Thanks to the help of the great people below i have gotten to this state. But am still facing some syntax errors.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Show the queries you tried from SAS and any errors, warning or notes that were logged.  In SQL Server pass through use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Use `intnx()` to align both the datetime of interest and today's datetime to the start of the week.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select *
        from table
        where intnx('dtweek', date, 0, 'B') = intnx('dtweek', datetime(), 0, 'B')
   ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response here, Stu!  I am getting a CLI describe error saying intnx is not a recognized built in function name.. i have using a odbc server pass through if that makes a difference. Also curious, what does the 'b'? blank?

Comment: If you're using SQL passthrough, you're effectively running SQL on another server through SAS. The SQL you use is dependent on the flavor of SQL within the database you're querying. You'll need to either use a date alignment function built into that version of SQL, or pull some of the data into SAS and use SAS SQL for post processing. "B" in `intnx()` says to align the date to the beginning of the time period. It takes the other arguments, "S" for same period and "E" for end of period.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out - if you are using SQL pass-thru, you need to use date functions that exist in your "flavor" of SQL.  SAS specific functions will not work, and in particular SAS function "today()" has no meaning in the SQL you are working with.

The approach I would take is:

1. in a SAS datastep - get today's date
2. use today's date to calculate beginning and end of the week
3. convert beginning/end dates to character strings
   (string will depend on how dates are formatted in your sql database - date or datetime)
4. use character strings to create macro variables
5. feed macro variables into sql pass-thru query to subset dates wanted

Below is some example code.  It might not get you all the way there, but could give you some more ideas to try.

```
data have;
    today = today();    *** TODAYs DATE ***;
    wkday = weekday(today); *** WEEK DAY NUMBER FOR TODAY, POSSIBLE VALUES ARE 1-7 ***;

    start = today - (wkday - 1);    *** CALCULATE SUNDAY ***;
    end = today + (7 - wkday);  *** CALCULATE SATURDAY ***;

    *** UNCOMMENT AND USE BELOW IF WEEK START/END IS MON-FRI ***;
    *start = today - (wkday - 2);   *** CALCULATE MONDAY ***;
    *end = today + (6 - wkday); *** CALCULATE FRIDAY ***;

    *** REPRESENT DATES AS DATE-TIME CHARACTER STRING - SURROUNDED BY SINGLE QUOTES ***;
    cstart = "'" || put(start, date9.) || ' 00:00:00.0000' || "'";
    cend =  "'" || put(end, date9.) || ' 00:00:00.0000' || "'";

    *** USE CHARACTER VARIABLES TO CREATE MACRO VARIABLES ***;
    call symput('start', cstart);
    call symput('end', cend);
run; 


*** IN SQL PASS-THRU, USE MACRO VARIABLES IN WHERE STATEMENT TO SUBSET ONE WEEK ***;
Proc Sql
    connect to odbc (environment=x user=y p=z);
      create table basic.curweek as select * from connection to odbc
           (select year, month, week, store, sales, SKU
                from datatable
                where (&start. <= week and week <= &end.)
                order by sku);
     disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Comment: Hey Sunny, I really like this idea here! I played with the dates a little bit and i cant get them to match up exactly as i can only add .0 to the end whereas my system has .000 at the end of the datetime but i dont think this will be a huge deal  edit: forgot to mention i am getting an "incorrect syntax near '<'. but i am working on trouble shooting that

Comment: Hi Blues, Glad this helped. Some more suggestions for you. Regarding the datetime – I originally set a length of $20 for character string.  I updated code above to use length $30 and added more zeros to time part to match your example.  For the problem near ‘<’, I suspect the issue is a macro quoting issue.  If your SQL query needs single quotes around datetimes - you can incorporate single quotes in the character string, and then in the query reference the macro variables directly without quotes.  I put some commented code to show what I’m talking about for the macro variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the length of 20.. bit mad at myself for not noticing that. i also fixed the < issue. I used where ("&start." <= week and week  <= "&end.").

Comment: thought i updated the above comment but now i am getting an invalid column name '20dec2020:00:00.000' after it runs the order by in the proc sql

Comment: `"` is not valid in passthrough SQL as a quotation character, it's the column delimiter, so you have to either include the `'` character in the macro variable when creating it, or use macro quoting to allow the macro variable to resolve while still having the single quotes around it.  In this case the `'` are already embedded, so you need to remove the `"` and just say `where (&start. <= week <= &end.)`.

Comment: Thats great feedback Joe! That did solve the column issue but now it is just saying inccorect syntax near 'Dec2020.'  saying that it has already been declared and label names must be unique.. is this happenining because both the &start and &end begin with DEC2020?

Comment: From the description of your error I think you still have a macro quoting issue. I updated example code again to follow Joe's comment about removing quotes in sql query.  And in datastep, macro strings are created to have single quotes.

Comment: @SunnyRJ, When i run the code i am no longer getting errors but it does not stop running. I let it run for 15 minutes real time before i cancelled the statements and the CPU time is under a second.